# Angular Typescript, dealing with return data you are unsure of. Typecasting

Tags: angular, typescript, types

How does one deal with a request with data you are not sure about and type checking.

To give a basic idea of what I mean, say I have an http call to an api, where random things can come back, but my component needs to work with an object that has an interface.

I have a more simple example below. Answer to simple example below too!

```
 export interface IComponentData {
    copy1: string;
    total: string;
}

/* ----- */

componentCopy: IComponentData; // component data


componentCopyLoaded(data: { status: string; data: IComponentData }): void {
    if (data.status === 'error') {
        this.isError = true;
    } else if (data.status === 'success') {
        this.componentCopy = data.data; 
    }
}


 ngOnInit(): void {
      this.subscriptions.add(
          this.getService
              .getSomeData('someurl')
              .subscribe(
                  data => this.componentCopyLoaded(data), <-ERROR HERE
                  error => this.componentCopyLoaded(error)
              )
        );
    }
```

What the error says is

```
> Argument of type '{ status: string; data: {}; }' is not assignable to
> parameter of type '{ status: string; data: IComponentData; }'. Types
> of property 'data' are incompatible. Property 'total' is missing in
> type '{}' but required in type 'IComponentData'.ts(2345)
```

Of course i can just make the interface properties optional, ie **total?: string** and the errors disappear but I might as well use any.

I have tried to use generics or extenting, but this is where I get lost, how does one get this to work?

eg

```
componentCopyLoaded<T>(data: { status: string; data: T }) <- does this make the data generic?
```

**Simple example**

```
export interface IDataInterface {
    total: number;
}

data: IDataInterface;

dataReturned(data: IDataInterface): void {
    this.data = data;
}

sendData() {
    // I want to put an object in with any kind of data structure
    // Pretend this is a general service that does an api call to anywhere. 
    this.dataReturned({total: 1}); <-- this works, sometimes data is this
    this.dataReturned({}); <-- this does not, sometimes data is this
}
```

**How it was fixed.**
Thanks to *joshvito* pointing me in the right direction.

So the error was as the image shows
[image]

And the fix is

[image]

To remove that error the simple example I added this instead

```
dataReturned(data: unknown): void { <-- add unknown
    this.data = data as IComponentData; <-- this line removed the Type error
}

sendData() {
    this.dataReturned({total: 1}); 
    this.dataReturned({});
}
```

Comment: What? What *is* `getSomeData`? Give a [mre]. And what do you mean *"does this make the data generic"*?

Comment: getSomeData is a service to a behaviour subject. Essentially it does a http call for me and returns data.

Comment: Sure, but *how is it defined*? What's the API you're calling and what *does* it return? And so on.

Comment: The service is just a service that does an api call. The subscribe on that service is the data that comes back from the api http call. The "someUrl" string means I can put any link there. So any kind of data can come back. Question is, how do I assign the data returning (which can be random data) to the function that deals with it, ie I dont want to put any in the data param, I would like to do an interface. The chap below seems to understand it.

Comment: If you want to use generics, did you try reading https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html? Given that HttpClient , which you're calling, uses generics, you could look at that code for inspiration.

Comment: I added a more simple example to explain the issue.

Comment: That doesn't clarify anything - what you've posted *works*, if it's in a class: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQBFMZN8U0tc4BvAKDkbhglIBsAuOJAVwFsARmgDcdAL5062NpgDOsuABUAFsgDmtBnAAmJTAH4uRPeVQYcwUVt2kASsBg8oSYNoAUNzEeKlTlCwCUXABuEAjamkzMqrIAdJ5wALw6eqKMEpKMssBI2j6YbgGRTAD0JQRwAO6YKMwQcGA88DVwEAIAVsDY8MhVCDDKcDUAnnAA1sgREOgppHCyMFA83U7AWoxlcAAKUA45EQMICkdDcGo5aJhs82jBCNQDJDoQwAotmGAIcNhX1yxDSGGlWUaGAsTg62iR3iensjmcrjcNDq7C4AEY4GIAmlMeI6EA

Comment: Thank you, that generics link is helpful. Pity I got marked down, hopefully this helps some other newbs out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"...where random things can come back..." are they random, or is there a few interfaces you can infer dependent on how you call the endpoint. If the latter is true, your generic method will work, you just need to call it with the expected interface. Or can you write a base interface that the others can inherit from?

Probably adding a reproducible example or sharing the data types that are returned from the service call would be helpful for better guidance.

e.g.

```
componentCopy: IComponentData; // component data


componentCopyLoaded<T>(data: { status: string; data: T }): void {
    if (data.status === 'error') {
        this.isError = true;
    } else if (data.status === 'success') {
        this.componentCopy = data.data; 
    }
}


 ngOnInit(): void {
      this.subscriptions.add(
          this.getService
              .getSomeData('someurl')
              .subscribe(
                  data => this.componentCopyLoaded<IComponentData>(data), <-ERROR HERE
                  error => this.componentCopyLoaded<IErrorData>(error)
              )
        );
    }
```

Typescript has some great utility types too.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html
For instance, you could use `Partial` or `Required` in your method declaration.

```
componentCopyLoaded(data: { status: string; data: Partial<IComponentData> }): void {...
```

or

```
componentCopyLoaded(data: { status: string; data: Required<IRequiredData> }): void {...
```

Comment: Hi thank you joshvito, I am glad you understood the question. I read through that document and tried those already before posting. The error then moves to the **componentCopyLoaded** to the line where it says _this.componentCopy = data.data;_ and has the same error.

Comment: You can build a new object when you assign the value. e.g. if `IComponentData` is `interface IComponentData {prop1: true, prop2: number}`; then  `this.componentCopy = Object.assign({}, {prop1: false, prop2: null}, data.data)`;

Comment: This was the answer, very much appreciated.